# FUNÇÕES EXCEL PARA COMPARAR VALORES

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma macro escondida com alguns valores em varias colunas. Na minha aba principal e unica visível ao usuário, desejo comparar se o valor da celula J2 da Macro é maior que 4 , se for maior, na minha aba principal na celula J10 mostrar " APROVADO" , se menor que 4 e maior que 0 , mostrar "REPROVADO", se igual a 0 ,"NÃO POSSUI VALOR .
Estou tentando usar a função =SE mas não estou conseguindo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Há como reduzir a formula e também como tratar eventuais erros**.

**FÓRMULA REDUZIDA:**

Já que com duas condições não satisfeitas, a terceira é atendida, temos:

```
  =SE(Plan1!J2 > 4; "APROVADO"; SE(E(Plan1!J2 <= 4; Plan1!J2 >0); "REPROVADO"; "NÃO POSSUI VALOR"))
```

Se o valor **não é maior do que 4**, e não é ao mesmo tempo **menor do que 4** e **maior que zero**, **os números restantes são todos obrigatoriamente menores ou iguais a zero**.

**TRATAR EVENTUAIS ERROS:**

Valores **acima de dez** ou **negativos** indicam falha na entrada de dados, então faça assim:

```
=SE(Plan1!J2 > 10; "ERRO: VALOR MAIOR DO QUE DEZ!"; SE(Plan1!J2 > 4; "APROVADO"; SE(E(Plan1!J2 <= 4; Plan1!J2 >0); "REPROVADO"; SE(Plan1!J2 =0; "NÃO POSSUI VALOR";"ERRO: VALOR NEGATIVO!")))
```

Repare que primeiro é verificado **se o valor é maior do que dez**, e depois, **não sendo atendidas todas as condições seguintes**, só restam os **valores negativos**, então, basta indicar o erro no final!

Answer (score 2):

Partindo do pressuposto que a planilha em que esta a célula J2 chama-se PLAN1.
A formula da coluna J10 seria a seguinte:

```
   =SE(Plan1!J2 > 4; "APROVADO"; SE(E(Plan1!J2 <= 4;
 Plan1!J2 >0); "REPROVADO"; SE( Plan1!J2 = 0; "NÃO POSSUI VALOR")))
```

Comment: Obrigado Reginaldo , funcionou perfeitamente !!!

Comment: @MateusRocha Marque a resposta como aceita. Do lado esquerdo da resposta tem uma tag. Clique nela.